# Base requirements for RFID experiment

Tags: rfid

I'm quite new to the topic but I would like to conduct an experiment on how RFID wristbands in a hospital setting affects patient satisfaction compared to a control group that will not have RFID wrist bands. Currently, a lot of patient verification is required, resulting in asking the same patient (possibly) up to 10 times their name and date of birth.

To conduct this experiment I will need some equipment, and I hope to find some assistance in this forum.

My guess is I will need:

- Printed RFID wristbands (or at least an RFID transmitter with a
  unique code to identify the patient by)
- RFID reader

I'm very familiar with PHP and back-end programming, so my first goto would be some restful API design the RFID reader transmits the data to. Perhaps, it is also possible to link the RFID reader with e.g. a smartphone or iPad?

Then there is a practical question I have: will the RFID reader react on the RFID wristband nearest? Or how will this work?

I hope you guys can shed some light on the hardware requirements I need. Thank you for your time and insights.

Comment: RFID readers have a maximum distance they can read, it depends on what you are trying to do. Also be aware that if you are wanting to do this in the US, you need to be careful of HIPAA and data protection.

Comment: The assistent will be in front (or near) the patient (max. 1,5m distance). I'm from the Netherlands by the way.

Comment: The wristbands need to be single-use in that they can never work again once removed to prevent being worn by someone else. See http://www.nordicwristbands.com/en/product/tamperproof-rfid-wri for example. Removing the band should irreversibly break the circuit or antenna.